# Hybris Promotions Module - Capping the Buy X Get Y?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to cap a 'Buy X Get Y' at a specific quantity amount?  I'm hoping to offer a 'Buy 2, Get 2' free but I don't want the offer to roll up incrementally (i.e. I don't want a user to be able to buy 4 and get 4).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend ProductBOGOFPromotion with a "maxFree" or something. But this will not be the easiest thing to do, as the eval logic is in the jalo class. So you'll need a subclass so you can change this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the productpromotion type and create a new type of promotion and there in  new promotion you can define your firing logic.
And you can check out http://www.hybrishub.com

Answer (score 0):

`ProductBOGOFPromotion` has `freeCount` field where you can enter the number of the products you want to sell for free.